# Improve SELECT performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, etl

Right now i have a select query which basically does Table1 minus table2(Including records that are different) ,Left join and filter nulls.

My query is:

```
SELECT table1.serial_number, 
       table1.equip_account_number, 
       table1.equip_service_address_id, 
       table1.equip_ani_phone_number, 
       table1.equip_part_number, 
       table1.equip_polled_date, 
       table1.equip_zone_map, 
       table1.equip_return_value, 
       table1.equip_renewal_frequency, 
       table1.equip_last_renewal_date, 
       table1.equip_in_stock_date, 
       table1.equip_assigned_addresses, 
       table1.equip_link_to_serial_number, 
       table1.equip_converter_type, 
       table1.equip_converter_id, 
       table1.equip_converter_model, 
       table1.equip_converter_options, 
       table1.equip_converter_value, 
       table1.equip_emp_code, 
       table1.equip_vendor_code, 
       table1.equip_headend_code, 
       table1.equip_distributor_code, 
       table1.equip_manufacturer_code, 
       table1.equip_location_code, 
       table1.equip_group_code, 
       table1.equip_ownership_code, 
       table1.equip_secondary_conv_info, 
       table1.equip_secondary_conv_type, 
       table1.equip_second_conv_manufacturer, 
       table1.equip_second_conv_install_date, 
       table1.call_back_cycle_day, 
       table1.call_back_last_date, 
       table1.call_back_request_date, 
       table1.trx_equip_status_code, 
       table1.trx_equip_reason_code, 
       table1.tv_ind, 
       table1.int_ind, 
       table1.tel_ind, 
       table1.dwh_create_date, 
       table1.dwh_update_date, 
       table1.equip_outlet_location_code, 
       table1.equip_return_date_due, 
       table1.equip_unrecovered_ind, 
       table1.equip_delete_date, 
       table1.install_date, 
       table1.work_order_number, 
       table1.ds_work_order_number, 
       table1.disconnect_emp_code, 
       table1.disconnect_date, 
       table1.ds_equip_location, 
       table1.equip_active_in_tv_ind, 
       table1.equip_active_in_tel_ind, 
       table1.equip_active_in_int_ind, 
       table1.equip_active_intv_change_date, 
       table1.equip_active_intel_change_date, 
       table1.equip_active_inint_change_date, 
       table1.pirat_ind, 
       table1.pirat_ind_change_date, 
       table1.equip_owner 
FROM   dim_equip, 
       scd_equip 
WHERE  table2.dwh_end_date(+) = To_date('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
       AND ( table2.serial_number IS NULL 
              OR ( table1.equip_account_number <> table2.equip_account_number 
                    OR table1.equip_service_address_id <> 
                       table2.equip_service_address_id 
                    OR table1.equip_ani_phone_number <> 
                       table2.equip_ani_phone_number 
                    OR table1.equip_part_number <> table2.equip_part_number 
                    OR table1.equip_polled_date <> table2.equip_polled_date 
                    OR table1.equip_zone_map <> table2.equip_zone_map 
                    OR table1.equip_return_value <> table2.equip_return_value 
                    OR table1.equip_renewal_frequency <> 
                       table2.equip_renewal_frequency 
                    OR table1.equip_last_renewal_date <> 
                       table2.equip_last_renewal_date 
                    OR table1.equip_in_stock_date <> table2.equip_in_stock_date 
                    OR table1.equip_assigned_addresses <> 
                       table2.equip_assigned_addresses 
                    OR table1.equip_link_to_serial_number <> 
                       table2.equip_link_to_serial_number 
                    OR table1.equip_converter_type <> 
                       table2.equip_converter_type 
                    OR table1.equip_converter_id <> table2.equip_converter_id 
                    OR table1.equip_converter_model <> 
                       table2.equip_converter_model 
                    OR table1.equip_converter_options <> 
                       table2.equip_converter_options 
                    OR table1.equip_converter_value <> 
                       table2.equip_converter_value 
                    OR table1.equip_emp_code <> table2.equip_emp_code 
                    OR table1.equip_vendor_code <> table2.equip_vendor_code 
                    OR table1.equip_headend_code <> table2.equip_headend_code 
                    OR table1.equip_distributor_code <> 
                       table2.equip_distributor_code 
                    OR table1.equip_manufacturer_code <> 
                       table2.equip_manufacturer_code 
                    OR table1.equip_location_code <> table2.equip_location_code 
                    OR table1.equip_group_code <> table2.equip_group_code 
                    OR table1.equip_ownership_code <> 
                       table2.equip_ownership_code 
                    OR table1.equip_secondary_conv_info <> 
                       table2.equip_secondary_conv_info 
                    OR table1.equip_secondary_conv_type <> 
                       table2.equip_secondary_conv_type 
                    OR table1.equip_second_conv_manufacturer <> 
                       table2.equip_second_conv_manufacturer 
                    OR table1.equip_second_conv_install_date <> 
                       table2.equip_second_conv_install_date 
                    OR table1.call_back_cycle_day <> table2.call_back_cycle_day 
                    OR table1.call_back_last_date <> table2.call_back_last_date 
                    OR table1.call_back_request_date <> 
                       table2.call_back_request_date 
                    OR table1.trx_equip_status_code <> 
                       table2.trx_equip_status_code 
                    OR table1.trx_equip_reason_code <> 
                       table2.trx_equip_reason_code 
                    OR table1.tv_ind <> table2.tv_ind 
                    OR table1.int_ind <> table2.int_ind 
                    OR table1.tel_ind <> table2.tel_ind 
                    OR table1.equip_outlet_location_code <> 
                       table2.equip_outlet_location_code 
                    OR table1.equip_return_date_due <> 
                       table2.equip_return_date_due 
                    OR table1.equip_unrecovered_ind <> 
                       table2.equip_unrecovered_ind 
                    OR table1.equip_delete_date <> table2.equip_delete_date 
                    OR table1.install_date <> table2.install_date 
                    OR table1.work_order_number <> table2.work_order_number 
                    OR table1.ds_work_order_number <> 
                       table2.ds_work_order_number 
                    OR table1.disconnect_emp_code <> table2.disconnect_emp_code 
                    OR table1.disconnect_date <> table2.disconnect_date 
                    OR table1.ds_equip_location <> table2.ds_equip_location 
                    OR table1.equip_active_in_tv_ind <> 
                       table2.equip_active_in_tv_ind 
                    OR table1.equip_active_in_tel_ind <> 
                       table2.equip_active_in_tel_ind 
                    OR table1.equip_active_in_int_ind <> 
                       table2.equip_active_in_int_ind 
                    OR table1.equip_active_intv_change_date <> 
                       table2.equip_active_intv_change_date 
                    OR table1.equip_active_intel_change_date <> 
                       table2.equip_active_intel_change_date 
                    OR table1.equip_active_inint_change_date <> 
                       table2.equip_active_inint_change_date 
                    OR table1.pirat_ind <> Nvl(table2.pirat_ind, 0) 
                    OR table1.pirat_ind_change_date <> 
                       NVL(table2.pirat_ind_change_date, 
                       TO_DATE('01/01/0001', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) 
                    OR table1.equip_owner <> table2.equip_owner) )  
       AND table1.serial_number = table2.serial_number(+)
```

`Table1` have only Unique index and PK - `SERIAL_NUMBER`

`Table2` have Unique index and PK - `DWH_SERIAL_KEY`
and normal indexes - `DWH_END_DATE, EQUIP_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SERIAL_NUMBER`.

`Table1` have 13MIL records and table2 have a lot more but after the first condition`(END_DATE=2999)` it returns 13MIL records to.

The query takes about 10-25minutes depending each day on the amount of data that arrives.

Any thoughts on how to make it faster will be appriciated.

Comment: Can't you simply check whether `dwh_update_date` is more recent than your last ETL processing date instead?

Comment: Nope, can't relay on that @mef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you wrote and the variants using `MINUS` require all columns to be compared, causing the performance problem.

#### recommended approach

I recommend updating the way how your tables are modelled, in order to allow easier and faster identification of modified records.

For example, you could keep track of the last modification date of each records, as well as the date of the last execution of your data update process. comparing the last modification column to your timestamps would give you the desired records much more faster, as only one column would need to be compared.

#### workaround

If this is not an option for you, you may want to do the following instead:

(but really, try the recommended approach, this is what's used in the industry, and there's a reason for it).

Add an extra column `record_hash` to table1 and table2, populated with the following:

```
ora_hash(equip_account_number||equip_service_address_id||equip_ani_phone_number||...||equip_owner)
```

Just make sure to map all the columns inside ora_hash in the same way how you want to compare the records (use `nvl`s where appropriate).

Then you can do the minus logic in a much simpler way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 tb1, 
   ( -- this subquery compares record from both tables and returns the serial_number of all new/modified records inside table1
    SELECT table1.serial_number, 
       table1.record_hash 
     FROM   table1
  
      minus 
  
    select table2.serial_number, 
       table2.record_hash
    From   table2
    WHERE  table2.dwh_end_date = to_date('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ) diff
 where diff.serial_number = tb1.serial_number
```

`ora_hash` is [documented here](http://stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/functions097.htm).

also: read about [collisions](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/ora_hash-function/).

Comment: agreed about the recommended approach. at the very first time i saw this, i guessed it's a normal dim table and its SCD table, so i really doubt about  when you set the end date to 2999 still would get multiple records, i think there should be a way to get 1 to 1 serial number and that would be make your query much faster

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code seems you want selevt the value of a set not in other set
If you are using Oracle the you can use also the minus clause per operation over sets .

Your second part of query ...

```
  AND ( table2.serial_number IS NULL 
          OR ( table1.equip_account_number <> table2.equip_account_number 
                OR table1.equip_service_address_id <> 
                   table2.equip_service_address_id 
                OR table1.equip_ani_phone_number <> 
                   table2.equip_ani_phone_number ...
                 ......
```

could be easily change in a minus select of the data in table 2 respect the data in table1

the code below is just a partial sample ( a suggestion)

```
SELECT table1.serial_number, 
   table1.equip_account_number, 
   table1.equip_service_address_id, 
   table1.equip_ani_phone_number, 
   table1.equip_part_number, 
   ......
   ......
   table1.pirat_ind, 
   table1.pirat_ind_change_date, 
   table1.equip_owner 
FROM   table1, 


minus 

select table2.serial_number, 
   table2.equip_account_number, 
   table2.equip_service_address_id, 
   table2.equip_ani_phone_number, 
   table2.equip_part_number, 

WHERE  table2.dwh_end_date(+) = To_date('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
   AND table2.serial_number IS NULL;
```

Comment: Unfortunately , it took 1 minute longer than my query :\

Comment: Strange, very strange, try  also with a proper index on date ( if is possibile without transform todate.) and on  serial_number..also what @Raffaello.D.H. is useful.

Answer (score -1):

basically Edge is right but about minus he got a little thing wrong the serial nuber IS NULL is not needed and no comma after table1 i think should be :

```
  SELECT table1.serial_number, 
     table1.equip_account_number, 
     table1.equip_service_address_id, 
     table1.equip_ani_phone_number, 
     table1.equip_part_number, 
     ......
     ......
     table1.pirat_ind, 
     table1.pirat_ind_change_date, 
     table1.equip_owner 
   FROM   table1

    minus 

  select table2.serial_number, 
         table2.equip_account_number, 
         table2.equip_service_address_id, 
         table2.equip_ani_phone_number, 
         table2.equip_part_number, 
         ......
         table2.equip_owner
  From   table2
  WHERE  table2.dwh_end_date(+) = To_date('31/12/2999', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

but i'm not sure how much faster could this be.
hope this could help you and if you got a result, please let us know, really interested about this question :)

Comment: and the "**(+)**" is no longer relevant either

Comment: Unfortunately , it took 1 minute longer than my query :\